# Python injecting macro into Microsoft Word Objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, vba, windows, ms-word

i have had this problem for quite a while and cant figure it out at all. I checked the docs checked everything but cant seem to find how to inject a macro.
Here is my current code:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
instance = Dispatch("Word.Application")
instance.Visible = False
objdoc = instance.Documents.Open(docpath)
macro = objdoc.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
macro.CodeModule.AddFromString(macrocode)
objdoc.SaveAs(pathtosave)
instance.Quit()
```

Now the key line is `objdoc.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)` for adding the macro, i checked all `types` that it had and there wasnt a type corresponding to `Microsoft Word Objects`, so i am clueless any help appreciated!

Comment: In Word you need to make sure *File >> Options >> Trust Center >> Trust Center Settings >> MacroSettings >> Trust Access to VBA project object model* is checked or you can't interface programmatically with the VB project.

Comment: Yeah, i did have that, i could add macro programmatically, but i couldnt find on documents or anywhere where to add macro on Microsoft Word Objects, only on Modules.

Comment: If you don't want to add a module what do you want to do?  It's not clear from your question.  What does the code you're adding do?

Comment: i want to add this macro code into the Microsoft Word Objects (this document)
```
Private Sub {somename}
some code
End Sub
```
But the thing is, i cant really find the command to inject macro into Microsoft Word Objects(this document), only to inject into a module
Let me show an example:
https://imgur.com/l3bbDfL

Let me know if i haven't fully explained something

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python programmer, but here's the VBA version:

```vba
    Dim objdoc As Document, module
    
    Set objdoc = ThisDocument
    
    'get existing code module
    Set macro = objdoc.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisDocument").CodeModule
    
    macro.addfromstring "Sub Hello()" & vbCrLf & _
                        "Msgbox(""OK"")" & vbCrLf & _
                        "End Sub"
```

Useful reference here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's the same thing since i use Word.Application from a shell. Worked like a charm.